# Shopify webhook failing to return a successful response

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I have created shopify app in which I have used webhooks for checkout/update. Webhook is working fine but I am getting this error message.

> Your webhook for checkouts/update
>   at https://www.smsblitz.io/smsblitz/abondoned?shop=smsblitz.myshopify.com&user=iman%5Egemconsultinginc.org is
>   failing to return a successful response.This webhook has been
>   attempted 23 times. If your webhook continues to fail, it will be
>   removed and your application will not receive any more notifications.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Initially I had the same problems. Following things could be taken care for getting out of the above issue.

- Do not wait till you process the data in the notification. Soon after you get the webhook data, send back a 200 ok status code and then go further processing.
- Make sure there is no white space before php tag or there is no echo statement available before you send the 200 status code to shopify because that will end up with error - header already sent.
- Do not sleep with a timer as shopify wait for a 5 second time window and expect your 200 status code in between that time span.
- You can save your processed data/id in a database. Shopify sends a webhook notification around 19(they say but sometimes more in real) times. So, you can try with first check with your database that the webhook notification is already processed by you or not. If processed send a 200 OK immediately.

Webhooks created through API are more reliable than the one created manually through the Shopify admin. (Though shopify claims they treat them same.)

Comment: Hello Debashis Dash,

Thanks for the reply.
you mean to say that when i got response from webhook and after collecting the data I need to send response to shopify like header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); and then do further processing in the same function.right?
$Data = file_get_contents("php://input");
after this line i need to add header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); and then continue with further functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. and make sure the link associated with the webhook must be a globally accessible link. It should not be a localhost link. The best practice would be maintaining the webhook data fetching and sending header in a separate php file. After sending the header 200, You can call the function through CURL. (Where logical operation for the webhook data is written.)

Comment: Hello Debashis Dash,

thanks for the response. Can you please send me simple example so that I can help me in better understanding.

Thanks

Comment: You can try something like this.

<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
<!-- process the webhook data -->
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, <API_link_to_the_function>);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$ack = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>

Comment: Even, I used same code which is <?php $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK'); <!-- process the webhook data --> still webhook triggers multiple times and not working as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Your webhook is not working fine. It is failing to respond to Shopify. So until you fix that, Shopify is counting the failures and letting you know, that soon, they will just stop that Webhook, and you'll have to recreate it.

To solve the issue, POST a webhook to your endpoint and verify it returns a 200 OK.

Comment: Hello David,

Thanks for the reply.
In my webhook I have get abandoned cart data and used php sleep function to wait for 5 mins and then send text message to the customer, which is working fine. So, can you please explain a little more what should i need to do now?

Thanks

Comment: Receive the Webhook. Trigger a background job to deal with the customer. Send Shopify a 200 OK. Make sure you respond < 5 seconds to Shopify. Your problem is you use SLEEP which means Shopify never gets your 200OK which means they delete your webhook.